# Contar click y mostrarlo en pantalla, pero que al recargar no reinicie el conteo, ya sea con JavaScript o Php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola amigos quisiera saber como hacerle para que me cuente los numero de click que le haga a una parte de una pagina , y mostrarlo, quisiera hacerlo con php para que asi esos click se guarden en la Base de datos pero es mas facil con javascript pero al recargar me reinicia el conteo..

Saludos y les anticipo las gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo mas recomendable es que aprendas jquery ya sea que no lo entiendas si o si por que basicamnete es algo verdaderamente necesario o casi obligatorio por asi decirlo y la sintaxy es muy facil mira este ejemplo

```
$(document).click(

    //hacemos una llamada ajax a un archivo php que guardara el click ejemplo
       $.ajax({

        url:"guardar_click.php",
        success:function(data){
           alert(data)
        }
       })

    });
```

**guardar_click.php**

```
<?php

//por ejemplo esta sentecia sql actualisaria cada click que des 
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE guardar_click SET click=click+1");

 $row=mysqli_fecht_array($sql);

 echo $row["click"];//retornamos el numero de veces que se ha clikeado

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

si usas jQuery puedes intentar lo siguiente

```
$(document).click(
   $.post("guardarClick.php")
);
```

y en el PHP solo guardarias +1 a un contador en alguna base de datos

Comment: Estaba usando php sin nada de nada , pero jquery no uso, ya que no lo manejo mucho, pero si tienes alguna pagina o algun ejemplo podria agradecerte

Comment: lo mas recomendable es que aprendas jquery ya sea que no lo entiendas si o si por que basicamnete es algo verdaderamente necesario o casi obligatorio por asi decirlo y la sintaxy es muy facil