# Problemas al Contrar Click en un enlace <a> con Php, Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Buen dia , he estado revisando una pagina y me encargaron hacer un trabajo que cada vez que haga click en una etiqueta  especifica cuente los click en una base de datos , al hacer click abre un modal que es obtenido por jquery o ajax..
No entiendo mucho sobre ajax pero quisiera saber como hacerlo con estos codigos.
Gracias

**Codigo html**

```
<a  href="#" class="citar-documento" title="Citar documento" ></a>
 .......
 .......

 <script>
  $('.citar-documento').click(function(){
    $.confirm({
    'title'     : 'Cita en formato APA 6ta., versi&oacute;n',
    'message'   : 'Durán, A. (2018) Las encrucijadas en el arte mexicano. <i>Espacio I+D Innovación más Desarrollo, 7</i>(17) 30-44.',
    'articulo'         : 'a2', /* a1 = numero de articulo, r15 = no. revista, v6= volumen 6, borrar este comentario al final de la edición */
    'idcita'    :'114',
    'buttons'   : {
        'Cerrar'    : {
            'class' : '',
            'action': function(){}//Sin actividad...
            }
            }
        });
    });

  </script>
```

**Js**

```
(function($){

    $.confirm = function(params){

        if($('#confirmOverlay').length){
            return false;
        }

        $dato = params.idcita;
        window.location.href = "../../../citas.php?count_cita="+$dato;
    };


}
)(jQuery);
```

**Php**

```
 <?php
 include_once 'conexion.php';
 if(isset($_GET['count_cita']))
 {
 $idarticulo = $_GET['count_cita']; 
 $mysqli = new mysqli($hostbd,$usuariobd,$clave,$basededatos);
 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE Id=".$idarticulo;
 $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql_query);
 $fetched_row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$CitadoActual=$fetched_row['Citado'];
$Click=$CitadoActual+1;
$Url=$fetched_row['Url'];
$sql_Actualizar = "UPDATE articulos SET Citado='$Click' WHERE 
Id=".$idarticulo;



 }
if($actualiza=$mysqli->query($sql_Actualizar))
{

  header("Location:$Url?id=$idarticulo#"); 
  }

?>
```

Comment: El envias el parametro `count_id` pero en la pagina de PHP recibes `count_cita`

Comment: Si ya o corregi y nada, lo que quiero es contar , pero quiero ahorrar codigo porque cuando entra al php me recarga de nuevo la pagina y nada

Comment: comprobaste ninguna variable está vacía? imprime la variable $sql_Actualizar a ver si la consulta se ve de forma correcta

Comment: [mira esta pregunta que respondi quisas te puedad aclarar como se aria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186699/contar-click-y-mostrarlo-en-pantalla-pero-que-al-recargar-no-reinicie-el-conteo/186707#186707)

Comment: Si tiene sentido men lo que me pusiste primero pero asi como me lo dices hay una linea donde dice Url y esa me manda al php pero ya que guarde quiero que me abra el modal que esta hecho con jquery creo .. con eso amigo quiero ayuda!